# How to make FlashDevelop use 32-bit JRE?

Tags: java, flash, flashdevelop

I need to have 64-bit JDK installed for Android Studio (this also means having `JAVA_HOME` set to 64-bit JDK).
I also have installed 32-bit JRE and in Flex SDK `jvm.config` file I specified path to it (I know Flex SDK uses it because I got Windows firewall warning about 32-bit `java.exe` starting up when I compiled my project).

But still in FlashDevelop I get `Error details: System.BadImageFormatException: Próbowano załadować program w niepoprawnym formacie. (Wyjątek od HRESULT: 0x8007000B)`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Android Studio can be launched in 32 bit mode also, are you aware of that ?

Comment: @xwid Is it possible without reinstalling it?

Comment: there is bin/studio.exe in your Android studio installation directory, it runs android stuido in 32-bit mode and bin/studio64.exe runs in 64-bit mode

Answer (score 2):

Install a [32-bit JRE 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html) (*not* 1.8) and specify the path to it in `Flex SDK/bin/jvm.config` like this:

```
java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.7.0_71
```

Note: On Windows replace all backslashes with forward slashes.

Note: `java.exe` must also be on the `PATH`, but it can be a 64-bit version. As long as any `java.exe` is on the PATH, the JRE from `jvm.config` will be used by Flex SDK.